# Fill input search field with javascript (field dynamically displays results)

Tags: javascript, html, autofill, dom-manipulation

I am trying to automatically fill in a search field using javascript. The website dynamically displays results for the input in real time while typing in.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("input1")[0].value = "Number";
```

```html
<label class="label1">
  <input type="search" data-testid="text-input" class="input1"> 
  <span class="label">city, street or name</span>
</label>
```

When running the code the desired value is also displayed in the search field, however the search won't execute. When clicking into the field manually, deleting a character and entering it again manually the search executes. I already tried different approaches on simulating keyboard input but none of them worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for **placeholder attribute in HTML**, if you update value via JS, it will update the value and your listener will run the respective function

```html
<input type="search" data-testid="text-input" class="input1" placeholder="Enter something">
```

**If you are only looking it to update via JS,** you can also try changing placeholder attribute, like this:

```js
document.getElementById('searchId').placeholder='new placeholder';
```

```html
<input type="search" data-testid="text-input" id="searchId" class="input1" placeholder="Enter something">
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's listener that is called when `input` event is triggered .
You can check the event on which the needed function is called and programmatically emit that event from `input` element.